# How to list files changed in given branch

Tags: mercurial

I'm looking for a way to find a list of files edited in given branch. It's not merged to default yet. `hg diff` is too verbose for me.

I would like to filter any changes made by merge FROM default

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your best bet is probably `diff`'s `--stat` option:

```
ry4an@four:~/projects/mercurial$ hg diff -r default -r stable --stat mercurial/cmdutil.py     |   3 ---
 mercurial/help/dates.txt |   2 --
 mercurial/revset.py      |  34 +++++++++++-----------------------
 mercurial/util.py        |  15 ---------------
 tests/test-commit.t      |   2 --
 tests/test-parse-date.t  |  17 -----------------
 tests/test-revset.t      |  16 ++--------------
 7 files changed, 13 insertions(+), 76 deletions(-)
```

That shows the difference between the most recent (actually tipward) head in branch `default` and the most recent head in branch `stable` with a little summary of how substantially they've changed.

Comment: Sorry, I should have formulated the question better. The default branch has run forward and differs very much from the current branch, that was left unmerged into default. I need to check what was actually done in that branch.

Comment: If you want to know what's different between the head of `branch` and the most-recent-common-ancestor of `branch` and `default` ("where it split off") then you'd do this slightly trickier command: `hg diff --stat -r default -r 'ancestor(default, branch)'`  See `hg help revsets` for some other cool tricks.